# Can't start neo4j after HA issue

Tags: neo4j, high-availability

i'm having a real issue trying start neo4j at the moment. My setup consists in 2 servers which are in HA mode. Last night, server 1 logged the fact that there was a timeout trying to elect the master, and it was not available anymore. Server 2 seemed to work fine.

So i tried to restart server 1, and here's the log message i have :

```
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
05/07/13 09:52:57 org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper SEVERE:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@17f0d3b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:319)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:115)
        at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
        at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:299)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:132)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@17f0d3b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:296)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@3cbcef07' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:126)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such store[/home/neo-data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names] for org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction@7d6bab68
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:149)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.<init>(CommonAbstractStore.java:110)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractDynamicStore.<init>(AbstractDynamicStore.java:75)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.DynamicStringStore.<init>(DynamicStringStore.java:43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newDynamicStringStore(StoreFactory.java:153)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newRelationshipTypeTokenStore(StoreFactory.java:159)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.attemptNewNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:125)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:114)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:277)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
        ... 15 more
05/07/13 09:52:57 org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

I understand that there may be troubles with the data, but i can't find how to fix that.

I'm running neo4j 2.0M03 on ubuntu server appliances.

Thanks in advance for any help !
Gouffe

Comment: Well, to anyone who sees this post, i managed to get the data from server 2, and i reimported everything on server 1. It now works. I'm still interested in an answer for future references though.

Comment: can you share more details? E.g. your messages.log files? Can you send them to michael at neo4j dot org? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, i didn't keep all those log files. The fact is that now i've restored the stable version 1.9.1, everything seems to be working great! I'd say that the pre release version is not ready for HA yet.